# gridview rendered in div

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview inside a content template inside an update panel.
The aspx is like that:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ...>
   <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:Panel ...>
          ....
      </asp:Panel>

      <asp:GridView....>
          ....
      </asp:GridView>

      <asp:Panel>
          ....
      </asp:Panel>

    </ContentPanel>

  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The problem is that the rendered HTML looks like that when it comes to the gridview:

```
<div>
<table>
......
</table>
</div>
```

The table is wrapped in a div I have no control over. Any way to disable that? Or give it an ID so that I can control it with CSS?

Let me know if you've have the same issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure about this, because the Panel would result in rendering of a div not the grid-view which normally renders in table

Comment: @Naveed - OP is correct. I just tried it with only a `gridview` in a `form`. It renders as `<div><table>...</table></div>`.

Comment: what exactly do you want to format for the grid-view (div) then ?

Comment: @Naveed: I want to remove it!! If possible; else I want to give it an ID to control it in CSS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this : http://www.atashbahar.com/post/GridView-makeover-using-CSS.aspx

So you can do this :

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCustomres" ... 
CssClass="mGrid"  
PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"  
AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ListView` control to achieve that, and you can still maintain the same functions and concepts found `GridView`.

Try this: [Complete ListView](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24570/Complete-ListView-in-ASP-NET-3-5)